# OEM Unlocking Greyed out after Android 8.1 Update. (Lenovo Tab4 10)

Tags: wi-fi, adb, rooting, rom-flashing, factory-reset

I purchased a Lenovo Tab 4 10, I enabled OEM Unlocking, Unlocked the Bootloader to root my tablet, and when I booted back into the Android OS it had an update, so I updated it, rebooted, re-enabled Developer Options because it had turned it off after the Android update, now OEM Unlocking is greyed out, I've cleared cache, factory reset it, tried tricking it with dates, waited 10 days to see if there was a lock period, and it's still greyed out, tablet Bootloader now says "LOCKED" and I can not Re-enable OEM Unlocking to unlock my Bootloader again.

I'm Stuck and Any Help or Ideas would be Appreciated, I can find almost nothing on this tablet. so any help is greatly appreciated!
The Specs of my Lenovo Tab4 10 ( this is NOT the Plus or the LTE Version.) are below. :)
I Thank Everyone For Their Time :)

Model: Lenovo TB-X304F

Kernel Version: 3.18.71

Build Number: TB-X304F_S001014_181113_row

Hardware Version: Lenovopad TB-X304F

Software Version: TB-X304F_RF01_181113

RAM: 2GB

Storage: 16GB

CPU: Qualcomm Snapdragon 425

Comment: I had that problem too. NAT was the root cause.